# Ajax requests on native android apps

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have packaged a Sencha Touch 2 app with PhoneGap for Android. I can't get the ajax requests to work on my native application. When I handle the request through the browser on http://mydomain.com/mysenchaapp/android/assets/www/ it works fine, however, when I run my app through the emulator as a native app my request fails. I think it would be helpful if I could get fiddler to work on handling native apps' request as well, but I haven't been able to figure that out either. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a native application you can use cross-domain get requests without using JSONP. I got it to work. My problem accessing the servlet was another issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Ajax for Cross-Domain GET requests, you should use JSONP instead. Take a look at the documentation for `Ext.data.JsonP.request()`, You can however use Ajax to make a post if i'm not mistaken. This comes in handy when uploading something like a base64 string (which is too big for a GET request)